# Can't open android studio 4.1.x

Tags: android, android-studio

Since updating android studio to version 4.1.x I can't open it, it always produce same error output.

```
2020-11-29 19:36:09,916 [  89603]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283 
2020-11-29 19:36:09,916 [  89603]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-11-29 19:36:09,916 [  89603]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
2020-11-29 19:36:09,916 [  89603]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
2020-11-29 19:36:09,916 [  89603]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
```

For context: I use archlinux. I try to remove and purge, and try to reinstall, downloading manually, but I couldn't get past that point. Version 4.0.2 is working normally though. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Delete this folder :
C:\Users\ {user name} \AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Comment: not using windows, and that is internal plugin, so it can't be removed

Comment: Not helped to me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Android Studio 4.1 (and 4.2) on Windows. The Studio would not start with the error mentioned (in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.X\log\idea.log).

I have limited space on the C: drive so I routinely change installation folder from C: to D:. However it seems the update logic is flawed. Finally I managed to install AS 4.0 when I changed destination folder to a new one (still on the D: drive, but not the same as the previous installation, i.e. the one being uninstalled).

After installation AS asked to apply some patch and once the patch was applied, the same error again showed up on AS startup.
I re-installed 4.0 again (this time was not asked to apply any patch) and at the moment it seems to run (at least IDE is finally opened).