# Android Studio doesnt statrs on win10 x64

Tags: android-studio

i was update my android studio to `4.1.3.0` but now it cant start normaly ... on launch i can see preloading logo, then empty ide window, then all closes but studio proccess still in task manager.
Any idea?

*Update...*

I found log!

```
2021-03-29 23:25:52,454 [  51453]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.3  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,454 [  51453]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,454 [  51453]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,454 [  51453]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
2021-03-29 23:25:52,455 [  51454]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
    at com.intellij.featureStatistics.fusCollectors.LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.onError(LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.java:123)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.canHandle(DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.java:62)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.appendToLoggers(DialogAppender.java:85)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.lambda$queueAppend$0(DialogAppender.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:847)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2021-03-29 23:25:52,455 [  51454]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.3  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,455 [  51454]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,455 [  51454]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2021-03-29 23:25:52,455 [  51454]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
2021-03-29 23:25:52,456 [  51455]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
    at com.intellij.featureStatistics.fusCollectors.LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.onError(LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.java:123)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.canHandle(DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.java:62)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.appendToLoggers(DialogAppender.java:85)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.lambda$queueAppend$0(DialogAppender.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)

...
```

I see that uses JDK: 1.8.0_242, can i change it? cause i have installed JDK-16...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open android studio 4.1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064598/cant-open-android-studio-4-1-x)

Comment: What use should be JDK 16, when dealing with a broken installation? Don't think it's any advance.

Comment: yeah... that is... installer failure...

Answer (score 0):

Remove Cache folder From Android Root File From Your C Drive(Or the Drive you installed the android studio ) then re open android studio it will work

Comment: i did clean uninstall/install... but not working...there is no `cache` folder...